# Add html attributes to objects returned from Mage::getBlockSingleton

Tags: javascript, html, magento, php

How do I add an html class attribute to a block returned from

```
Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId())
```

in magento?

Is the only option to override the `getCountryHtmlSelect()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery,

```
$('#selectElementId').addClass('MyClass'); 
$('.selectElementClass').addClass('MyClass');
```

Using Plain Javascript,

```
document.getElementById("MyElementId").className += " MyClass";
```

Using PrototypeJS,

```
element.addClassName(className);
```

Or the other way, [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/m/viewthread/205803/#t479301) may help.

Comment: I'd rather not use js for such a minor thing. I was hoping there's already some built in function in magento to add classes to retrieved blocks.

Comment: Then did u check the link I gave in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying `Mage\Directory\Block\Data.php` from `app\code\core\` to `app\code\local` and modified the `getCountryHtmlSelect()` function `setClass()` order

Comment: That is what I added in answer also